# How to count the number of users from a table through views in laravel?

Tags: mysql, database, count, laravel-5.5

I'm working on a laravel 5.5 and I'm trying to count the number of users from a table and display the result from a view.

But I'm getting an error

> "Undefined Variable: count"

This is the function inside the controller:

```
public function admin(){

   $count = DB::select('select count(*) as total from users');
   return view('home',['count' => $count]);
}
```

This is the code inside the view **'home'**:

```
<tr>
   <td> Total Users </td>
   <td> Total Coaches </td>
   <td> {{$count}} </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given the variable in a string like this `['count => $count']`, so it didn't work.

Try the code as below in your controller:

```
public function admin()                                                    
{                                              
   $count = DB::select('select count(*) as total from users');
   return view('home', ['count' => $count[0]->total]);                      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
return view('home',['count => $count']);  
// Single quotation is on wrong place, array key will be wrapped with single quotation not the variable
```

change it to:

```
return view('home',['count' => $count]);
```

and on your view try:

```
{{ $count[0]->total }}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo when I uploaded the code here. Anyways that is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

it work for me

```
  use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
        
        
    $users_count = User::count();
    $users_today = User::where('created_at','>=',Carbon::now()->startOfDay())->count();
    $users_this_week = User::where('created_at','>=',Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(\Carbon\Carbon::SATURDAY)->startOfDay())->count(); // default startOfWeek() is Monday
    $users_this_month = User::where('created_at','>=',Carbon::now()->firstOfMonth()->startOfMonth()->startOfDay())->count();
    $users_this_year = User::where('created_at','>=',Carbon::now()->firstOfMonth()->startOfMonth()->startOfDay())->count();
```